# PHP: Showing Differences Between Two Strings

Tags: php, string, highlighting

Is there a functional String Difference Highlighting class/function out there for PHP?

This has been asked before [Highlight the difference between two strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php) but the answers given suggest PEAR's Text_Diff.

I tried using Text_Diff and found it was giving me a bunch of STRICT NOTICES and the examples given returned empty strings.

Errors like:

```
array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, non-static method Text_Diff::trimNewlines() should not be called statically
```

Answer (score 1):

Open '/framework/gii/components/Pear/Text/Diff.php' file. Locate the function `trimNewlines` and add a word `static`. Something like this:

```
static function trimNewlines(&$line, $key)
```

This may help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that one or more of the functions that PEAR package uses is not backward compatible with some earlier version(s) of PHP. Maybe just suppress the notice using [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/error_reporting) or (dare I say) with the [error suppression operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) '@'.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3 and the errors are for things like: "array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, non-static method Text_Diff::trimNewlines() should not be called statically"

Answer (score 0):

You could contact the maintainer of `Text_Diff` and report the errors. 5.3 is relatively new and it introduces a bunch of changes, so there are many projects that haven't been upgraded yet.

Comment: Most projects haven't even been updated for PHP5 in general, let alone 5.3 :(