# What is the most robust diff class/system/plugin for PHP?

Tags: php, diff

I know of the Text_Diff PEAR package, but is there anything more robust? I'm looking to take diffs of strings with HTML tags in them, and I'd like to know the locations of all the differences including the tags.

Comment: In what way is Text_Diff not robust enough for your needs?

Comment: I'm currently using Text_Diff on HTML (and have been for 2 years now) to drive an HTML-based wiki application.  It's not ideal, but it's sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PEAR `Text_Diff` package is the most complete I know, however if that doesn't fit your needs you can try [PHPDiff](http://www.holomind.de/phpnet/diff2.src.php) or the really simple [simplediff](http://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/blob/5bfe1d2a8f967c7901ace50f04ac2d9308ed3169/simplediff.php) from Paul Butler.

BTW, this has [been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php) before.

Answer (score -3):

What do you mean "for PHP?" ?

Diffs aren't language dependent. I use a diff plugin for my Text Editor (Vim).

Comment: If you're building, say, a PHP wiki, you need a way to do diffs in PHP itself.

Comment: well then his question should be better formulated.