# PHP nearest string comparison

Tags: php, string-comparison, similarity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String similarity in PHP: levenshtein like function for long strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092708/string-similarity-in-php-levenshtein-like-function-for-long-strings)

I have my subject string

`$subj = "Director, My Company";`

and a list of multiple strings to be compared:

`$str1 = "Foo bar";`
`$str2 = "Lorem Ipsum";`
`$str3 = "Director";`

What I want to achieve here is to find the nearest string related to `$subj`. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Please define "nearest".

Comment: You can try http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: @Kagat-Kagat: What do you mean by "nearest"?

Comment: Hi, here in my example, the nearest string woulb be is `$str3`, it is the nearest string to `$subj`.

Comment: Got it working, am not aware of `levenshtein()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `levenshtein()` function will do what you expect. The Levenshtein algorithm calculates the number of insert and replace actions being required to transform some string into another. The result is called an `edit distance`. The distance can be used to compare strings as you requested.

This example is derived from the documentation of the PHP [`levenshtein()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function.

```
<?php

$input = 'Director, My Company';

// array of words to check against
$words  = array('Foo bar','Lorem Ispum','Director');

// no shortest distance found, yet
$shortest = -1;

// loop through words to find the closest
foreach ($words as $word) {

    // calculate the distance between the input word,
    // and the current word
    $lev = levenshtein($input, $word);

    // check for an exact match
    if ($lev == 0) {

        // closest word is this one (exact match)
        $closest = $word;
        $shortest = 0;

        // break out of the loop; we've found an exact match
        break;
    }

    // if this distance is less than the next found shortest
    // distance, OR if a next shortest word has not yet been found
    if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
        // set the closest match, and shortest distance
        $closest  = $word;
        $shortest = $lev;
    }
}

echo "Input word: $input\n";
if ($shortest == 0) {
    echo "Exact match found: $closest\n";
} else {
    echo "Did you mean: $closest?\n";
}
```

Scripts output is

```
Input word: Director, My Company
Did you mean: Director?
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php to determine the distance between two strings.

```
$subj = "Director, My Company";
$str = array();
$str[] = "Foo bar";
$str[] = "Lorem Ipsum";
$str[] = "Director";

$minStr = "";
$minDis = PHP_INT_MAX;
for ($str as $curStr) {
  $dis = levenshtein($subj, $curStr);
  if ($dis < $minDis) {
    $minDis = $dis;
    $minStr = $curStr;
  }
}
echo($minStr);
```

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Also please relate to duplicate / similar questions first.