# Switch case, case was not found, but similar to the other case, give suggestion

Tags: php

We have something like this:

```
switch ($name)
{
    /** Prune **/

    case 'prune':
        echo 'Prune command: Deletes ALL of the messages from the chat.';
    break;

    /** Lock **/

    case 'lock':
        echo 'Lock command: Locks the chat, nobody can talk!';
    break;

    /** Unlock **/

    case 'unlock':
        echo 'Unlock command: Unlocks the chat, everybody can talk!';
    break;  

    /** Broadcast **/

    case 'broadcast':
        echo 'Broadcast command: Send a general broadcast message.';
    break;

    /** If command not found, echo suggestions.. **/

    default:
        echo 'Command not found, try these: /prune, /lock, /unlock, /broadcast';
    break;
}
```

We have a form that sends data, this data will be stored into a variable `$name`.

A user stored the following word: **prunne**.

Obviously, it will go to case default.

But what I want to do is, IF word is similar to any of the available cases, suggest the user.

For example, case prunne,

will echo: **Not found, did you mean Prune*?**

How do I do it?

Comment: You might want to check out the PHP implementation of the levenshtein algorithm, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php anyway your need a whole range of permutations for each case value, or your could do what your doing and make your user fix there mistake. or use a **list box** where they choose from the valid commands

Comment: IMO, do not overextend. Just list all the possible commands to user, let him choose and write correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can point you in the right direction:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Is a php function that can be used for your cause, there is a nice example on that page as well.

A related stack overflow question has more info on when your strings are longer than 255 characters:

[String similarity in PHP: levenshtein like function for long strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092708/string-similarity-in-php-levenshtein-like-function-for-long-strings)