# How to get this substr with a regex?

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

I have 2 strings :

```
Ass. Présentation Chiara D29,5cm
Ass. Présentation Chiara Anthracite D29,5cm
```

I need to keep only the word "Anthracite" in the second string, because this word is not in the first string

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Not with a single regex and no additional statements.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the other words will be in the same order in both strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight the difference between two strings in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php)

Comment: ArjunShankar >>> not especially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php

        $keywordString = "Ass. Présentation Chiara D29,5cm";
        $keywordArray  = explode(" ", $keywordString);        

        $string = "Ass. Présentation Chiara Anthracite D29,5cm";
        $stringArray = explode(" ", $string);


        foreach ($keywordArray as $keyword)
                $stringArray = preg_grep("/{$keyword}/i", $stringArray, PREG_GREP_INVERT);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($stringArray);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string into an array seperated by space, then remove the array with the lowest number of items from the one with the highest number of items, and all you would have left would be the word you need.

**EDIT:**

```
$string1 = "Ass. Présentation Chiara D29,5cm"
$array1 = explode(" ",$string1);

$string2 = "Ass. Présentation Chiara Anthracite D29,5cm"
$array2 = explode(" ",$string2);

$difference = array_diff($array2,$array1);
```

Comment: in this case i think you would make some logic that also detected the largest of the arrays and then subtracted the smallest, unless array_diff does that, been a while since i touched php :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the best way to go about it, but try using `explode` and `array_diff` like so:

```
$arr1 = explode(' ', $str1);
$arr2 = explode(' ', $str2);
$diff = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```

`$diff` would be an array of words that are present in `$str2` but not in `$str1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$words1 = explode(" ",$str1);
$words2 = explode(" ",$str2);

print_r(array_diff($words1,words2);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: This might work if `$str1` is the string containing `Anthracite` and `$str2` is the one without `Anthracite`.