# How to get difference between two words in php

Tags: php, string

I have a search engine for my website. I have installed a feature like Google's "Did you mean xxx?". It returns corrected string. So, is there a way so that I can compare both of those incorrect and correct strings and bold out the corrected words like Google do?

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 function suggestion($word){
    $first_word=substr($word,0,1);
    $first_word=strtoupper($first_word);
    $query="SELECT * FROM words WHERE UPPER(LEFT(name,1))='$first_word'";
    $db_words=mysql_query($query);
    $flag=true;
    while($row_words=mysql_fetch_array($db_words)){
        similar_text($row_words['name'],$word,$percent);
        if(($percent>50)&&($percent!=100)){
            echo '<strong>Did you mean:</strong><br>';
            echo $row_words['name'],'<br>';
            $flag=false;
        }
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php

Answer (score 3):

According to the comments below you are looking for something like this:

```
function corrected($bad, $good, $wholephrase) {
    return preg_replace('#\b'. preg_quote($bad) . '\b#g', '<em>' . htmlspecialchars($good) . '</em>', $wholephrase);
}
```

For those of you who were interested in how the detection of misspelling and suggestion of alternatives is accomplished take a look here: [Levenshtein Distance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: No, I already have got an algorithm using similar_text. Now, I want to make the corrections done in the string to be highlighted.

Comment: Then it'd be a great idea to actually ***paste*** your code so we can see what you're doing instead of guessing...

Answer (score 0):

No one helped me!! ;-(

Here is the code I created:

```
function suggestion($word){
    $first_word=substr($word,0,1);
    $first_word=strtoupper($first_word);
    $query="SELECT * FROM words WHERE UPPER(LEFT(name,1))='$first_word'";
    $db_words=mysql_query($query);
    $wd=explode(" ",$word);
    while($row_words=mysql_fetch_array($db_words)){
        similar_text($row_words['name'],$word,$percent);
        if(($percent>50)&&($percent!=100)){
            $rw=explode(" ",$row_words['name']);
            $d=array_udiff($rw,$wd,'strcasecmp');
            for($i=0;$i<count($rw);$i++){
                if(in_array($rw[$i],$d)){
                    $rw[$i]="<em>".$rw[$i]."</em>";
                }
            }
            echo '<strong>Did you mean:</strong><br>';
            foreach($rw as $r){
                echo $r," ";
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```