# Detecting similar structure of strings in PHP

Tags: php

Assuming I have the following two strings:

```
START dsad COMMAND5 name
```

```
START hfhsaklk342cxz COMMAND8 name
```

I want to be able to analyze and find the common structure between the strings:

```
START ### COMMAND### name
```

(### marks changing data).

(They all start with "START ", followed by something, then " COMMAND", then something, then " name")

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of looking for the common parts, you may be better off looking for the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php

Comment: It seem you already know the common parts. Can't you use a regular expression to parse those strings? Something like `'START\s([a-z0-9]*)\sCOMMAND[0-9]\sname'`

Comment: That's the problem - I don't know the common parts, this was just an example.

@JoeriSebrechts - Thanks, it didn't cross my mind to use Diff. I'll look into that!

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: The problem is, how do you know what different is for sure? This task is not a well specified. It is a clear AI problem.