# PHP Revisions Library (like StackOverflow)

Tags: php, revisions

Is there a PHP library out there that can do something like this for me?

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20353734/revisions

I'm looking to implement revisions where users can see what was added, changed and removed in posts.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xdiff.php

Comment: Just store the full versions in each case, and then use a PHP diff rendering library.

Answer (score 2):

My Favorite: [FineDiff](https://github.com/gorhill/PHP-FineDiff) ([demo](http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex?sample=1))

It allows you to specify the granularity up to character-level and is faster than [Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/).

More: [Highlight the difference between two strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php)