# How to pretty print variable difference in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using SimpleTest and the version I use has error messages like:

> Parameter expectation differs at parameter 2 with [Identical
>   expectation [Array: 9 items] fails with [Array: 9 items] as key list
>   [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine] does not match
>   key list [one, two, three, five, four, six, seven, eight, nine]] at
>   line [150]

which is pretty hard to make use of most of the time. I'd like to get better output, like comparing array side by side, maybe with an arrow at the difference, or in case of strings - highlighting the part that is different. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: No... there is NO easy way of doing this. You have to do it the hard way ;) hope this helps!

Comment: Some of the answers here might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/q/321294/1301076