# Is there a PHP library for comparing two paragraphs and show differences of inserted or deleted?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a lyrics importing website using PHP in CodeIgniter framework. In that website I need to compare the old lyrics and new lyrics after using editing.

I need to show what user deleted from previous and inserted.

Is there any algorithm or library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight the difference between two strings in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php)

Comment: Thank u. The same thing with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question has been answered here, although a little bit older question: [Highlight the difference between two strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php)

There are as well countless other "diff" packages/libraries available. They do not need to be CI specific in order for you to use it.

Comment: Thank you that is what I want. I was just search as how to compare.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you so much for your input. When you see a message that has already been answered, please click the "flag" option and then use "should be closed -> duplicate of".