# How can I compare two strings and determine their differences?

Tags: php, string

I have two strings like this:

```
$str1 = "this is
         a text";

$str2 = "this is a text
         which is edited";
```

As you see there is two difference between them, removed that `<br>` which is after `is` *(in the `$str1`)* and appending `whic is edited`. Now I need to detect those difference, How can I do that?

Actually I need to show to my website's users what's edited. Something exactly like stackoverflow edit page (which highlights the difference with *red* and *green* colors).

Comment: If you're using a *NIX system you can probably do something like `$diff = shell_exec("diff  <(echo "$string1" ) <(echo "$string2")");` (basically I suggest you just use diff or an equivalent tool for this and not reinvent the wheel).

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321294/highlight-the-difference-between-two-strings-in-php

Answer (score 1):

If you load the php extension xdiff, then the command xdiff_string_diff  will make an unified diff containing the differences between two strings for you.

```
<?
$str1 = "this is
         a text";
$str2 = "this is a text
         which is edited";

$diff = xdiff_string_diff($str1, $str2, 1);
if (is_string($diff)) {
    echo "Differences between two strings:\n";
    echo $diff;
}else{
    echo "The two strings look the same to me.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$Diff = str_replace($srt1, "", $str2);
```

Should work

Comment: `str_replace()` expects at least 3 parameters.

Comment: By the way, [your solution isn't what I need](https://3v4l.org/3AjuI), I'm trying to create something like [this](http://www.textdiff.com/)

Comment: Ok... but, if you reverse it it will give you what has been taken out too? Or am I too tired to think? Change places of str1 and str2